# Mysql O_DSYNC confusion

Tags: mysql, linux, filesystems, posix

According to mysql documentation on O_DSYNC (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method):

"O_DSYNC: InnoDB uses O_SYNC to open and flush the log files, and fsync() to flush the data files. InnoDB does not use O_DSYNC directly because there have been problems with it on many varieties of Unix. "

But calling fsync() forces the file to the synchronised I/O file integrity completion state (data and metadata), and The fdatasync() only forces the file to the synchronized I/O data integrity completion state. (no metadata)

So according to this mysql should use fdatasync() ant not fsync() to simulate O_DSYNC (which causes writes to be performed according to the requirements of synchronised I/O data integrity completion like fdatasync()). flag. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are missing anything here.

The InnoDB developers are being conservative. I expect that they tested `fdatasync` on a variety of Unix platforms, and discovered that this sometimes caused corruption on some systems. Similar to what they found with O_DSYNC.

Weighing data corruption against performance, the InnoDB developers are playing it safe, by using what's tested to "work" on the platforms that they tested.